# Spring Security application with database: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.jdbc.JdbcDaoImpl

Tags: database, spring, postgresql, security

I am developing an spring security application using postgres database but I can't resolve this errors:

```
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)   [rt.jar:1.7.0_25]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)  [rt.jar:1.7.0_25]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724) [rt.jar:1.7.0_25]
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/security/core/userdetails/jdbc/JdbcDaoImpl
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_25]
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:792) [rt.jar:1.7.0_25]
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142) [rt.jar:1.7.0_25]
at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.doDefineOrLoadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:327)
at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.defineClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:391)
... 110 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.jdbc.JdbcDaoImpl from [Module "deployment.SpringSecurityTest8.war:main" from Service Module Loader]
at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:190)
at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:468)
at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:456)
at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:398)
at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:120   )
... 115 more
```

and this is the spring-security-configuration.xml

```
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd">




 <http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
    <intercept-url pattern="/admin**" access="ROLE_ADMIN" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/emp**" access="ROLE_EMP" />
 </http>


<beans:bean id='dataSource' 
  class='org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource'>
<beans:property name='driverClassName' value='org.postgresql.Driver' />
<beans:property name='url' value='jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres' />
<beans:property name='username' value='postgres' />
<beans:property name='password' value='po' />
```

```
<authentication-manager>
  <authentication-provider>
    <jdbc-user-service
data-source-ref="dataSource"
users-by-username-query='SELECT username, "password", true FROM "DataB".users where username=?'
authorities-by-username-query='select u1.username, u2.authority from "DataB"."users" u1, 
"DataB"."authorities" u2 where u1.username = u2.username and u1.username     =?' />

  </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>
```

Someone can identify the problem? I spent a lot of time with this, and still can figure what's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have spring-security-core-$version in your classpath

If you are using maven, add this dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
    <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I added the spring-security-core-3.0.7 in my classpath but I have an other error : `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.security.web.util.AntUrlPathMatcher from [Module "deployment.SpringSecurityTest8.war:main" from Service Module Loader]
 at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:190)`

Comment: Instead you can add spring-security-web-$version to your classpath, this dependency will add both core an web modules if you are using maven

Comment: I'm not using maven but I added all  needed jars

Comment: If you are not using maven, you need to add those manually. I suggest to use maven in order to avoid this. If there are more dependencies you need to find and add them.

Comment: witch jar I must add to resolve this error ? I have the spring-security-web jar in my classpath I still have the same error :    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.security.web.util.AntUrlPathMatcher

Comment: Which version are you using? I can see that this class exist until 3.0.X version if you are using newer version you won´t find.

Comment: I'm using 3.0.7 version

Comment: Check if the class is in your classpath? I have reviewed and the class AntUrlPathMatcher is in that version. https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/3.0.7.RELEASE/web/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/web/util/AntUrlPathMatcher.java

Comment: I don't think that the problem is in the jar file because I have org.springframework.security.web-sources-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar in my classpath and it has the class AntUrlPathMatcher

Comment: You have added sources not binaries. You need another jar with .class files